# passing reference to the templates

Tags: c++

nowadays i m working on the templates .So, i got stuck in the following problem this is the code that fills the vector with random values and then count how many odd values are in it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
class Odd{
private:
    int c;
public:
    bool operator()(int x){return x%2!=0;}
};
template<typename T,typename Q>
int count_(T f1,T f2,Q& check){
    int count=0;
    while(f1!=f2)
    {
        count+=check(*f1);
        f1++;
    }
    return count;
}
int Rand(){
    return ((rand()%100)+1);
}
int main(){
    srand(time(0));
    vector<int> V(100);
    Odd O;
    generate(V.begin(),V.end(),Rand);
    cout<<count_(V.begin(),V.end(),O);
}
```

This works perfectly fine but when i pass T& in the arguments it gives error ..i.e

```
template<typename T,typename Q>
int count_(T& f1,T& f2,Q& check){
    int count=0;
    while(f1!=f2)
    {
        count+=check(*f1);
        f1++;
    }
```

I dont know why because this is the reference to the pointer so it will work perfectly fine ...plz HELP ..THANKX

Comment: Why do you need to pass them as reference? `V.begin()` and `V.end()` return temporary values, which can only bind to `const T&` or `T&&`.

Answer (score 1):

As AlchemicalApples pointed out in the comment, `V.begin()` and `V.end()` return rvalues, which can only be bound to `const` or rvalue references.

You don't really need to pass iterators by reference - they are cheap to copy. In fact, all STL algorithms take their iterator arguments by value.

Actually, you shouldn't ever pass iterators by reference, because your function would modify them, which is unexpected (none of the standard algorithms do that) and could lead to errors if you use these iterators further in the code.